# Raspberry pi 3 Kali Linux

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

Cuándo hago boot por primera vez en Kali Linux, en mi raspberry pi 3, me pide un nombre de usuario y una contraseña, creí que son las predefinidas: pi, raspberry. Pero dice que la contraseña es incorrecta.

Comment: user: root. password: toor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El **usuario** / user es: `root`
La **contraseña** / password es: `toor`

Puedes verlo en la web oficial: https://docs.kali.org/kali-on-arm/install-kali-linux-arm-raspberry-pi

> You should be able to log into **Kali** (as user **root**, using the password **toor**) and execute the **startx** command at the shell prompt to start up the XFCE desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que llego un poco tarde a dar la respuesta, pero si no me equivoco en las ultimas releases de Kali Linux también están poniendo de acceso predeterminado los siguientes valores:

- Username: kali
- PassWD: kali

Espero que te sirva en caso de que uses versiones posteriores.

Un saludo!!